# floating point to scaled int conversion

Tags: c, int, floating

I have a function below that uses floating point numbers `D1` and `D2`. They are variables in an equation.

I don't want to use floats I am constrained for memory on the embedded platform I developing for (floating point library is large). I would only like to use `int`s. So the function would return an `int` and use `int`s in the calculation.

For example instead of 22.95 degrees the function would return 229500 degrees.

Would anybody know how I calculate what values `D1` and `D2` should become?

The range of values of values returned by the function are -40 to 120 degrees.

The size of an `int` is 4 bytes.

```
float readTemperatureC()
{
  int val;                // Raw value returned from sensor
  float temperature;      // Temperature derived from raw value

  // Conversion coefficients from SHT15 datasheet
  const float D1 = -40.0;  // for 14 Bit @ 5V
  const float D2 =   0.01; // for 14 Bit DEGC

  // Fetch raw value
  val = readTemperatureRaw();

  // Convert raw value to degrees Celsius
  temperature = (_val * D2) + D1;

  return (temperature);
}
```

This is the function I want to convert to that only uses ints. 
    int readTemperatureC()
    {
      int val;                // Raw value returned from sensor
      int temperature;      // Temperature derived from raw value

```
  // Conversion coefficients from SHT15 datasheet
  const int D1 = ?;  // for 14 Bit @ 5V
  const int D2 = ?; // for 14 Bit DEGC

  // Fetch raw value
  val = readTemperatureRaw();

  // Convert raw value to degrees Celsius
  temperature = (val * D2) + D1;

  return (temperature);
}
```

Comment: What is the range of values returned by function `readTemperatureRaw`, and what is `sizeof int` on your platform?

Comment: Perhaps `long D1 = -40*10000L; int D2 = 100; return (_val * D2) + D1;`?

Comment: @MichaelWalz: The first one is the current implementation, and the second one is the desired implementation.

Comment: Beware of integer overflow that might not have happened when using `float`. I suggest using an integer type larger than `int` so that *intermediate steps* of a calculation do not overflow the `int` limits of the (scaled) final value, in those cases where there is a division involved.

Comment: @barakmanos OK, of course. We can delete the comments related to this issue.

Comment: BTW, you could simply do `_val / 100 + 40`, which does not involve any floating-point operations. If you want to avoid integer-division (for example, if you're calling this inside a loop, and your HW's arithmetic unit is optimized for multiply and shift operations, but not for division operations), then you need to specify this as part of your question.

Comment: In your question you write _The range of values of values returned by the function are -40 to 120 degrees_. Can you confirm you are talking about the `readTemperatureC` function ?

Comment: We need the range of **RAW** values (not the range of the calculated temperature).

Comment: And you still haven't mentioned what's preventing you from doing `_val / 100 - 40`.

Comment: @barakmanos I suppose the raw values go from 0 for -40°C to 16'000 for 120°C.

Comment: @MichaelWalz: Hmmmm... probably :) ... We still need an answer to my other question though...

Comment: Hi - I've updated my question and converted the code to c. Thanks

Comment: @logitechmouse - have you heard of fixed-point arithmetic? It's just a matter of using it to compute the answer of `result = (raw/100) - 40;` or of  course, `result = (raw * 1/100) - 40;` - The division one being preferable since it's unlikely you'll represent 0.01 precisely - you certainly dont want to introduce any errors prematurely, thus the division method is preferable.. You may even find that 8:8 fixed-point is adequate, though this will only give you a precision of 1/256 = 0.0039 - or 13 increments to make 0.05

Comment: @barakmanos True - deleting comment  (I had focused on this [comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40593418/floating-point-to-scaled-int-converison?noredirect=1#comment68423569_40593418)

Answer (score 1):

> instead of 22.95 degrees the function would return 229500 degrees.

Multiple the coefficients by 10,000 and use integer arithmetic.

```
// Conversion coefficients from SHT15 datasheet
// const float D1 = -40.0;  // for 14 Bit @ 5V
// const float D2 =   0.01; // for 14 Bit DEGC
const int D1 = (int) (-40.0*10000);
const int D2 = (int) (0.01*10000);
...
temperature = (_val * D2) + D1;
```

Note: OP states 4-byte `int`.

---

<strike>I have my doubts that the FP values of `-40.0` and `0.01` are correct after reviewing the [data sheet](https://www.sensirion.com/fileadmin/user_upload/customers/sensirion/Dokumente/Humidity_Sensors/Sensirion_Humidity_Sensors_SHT25_Datasheet_V3.pdf)</strike>

OP has [commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40593418/floating-point-to-scaled-int-converison/40595597?noredirect=1#comment68449503_40595597) the correct [data sheet](https://cdn-shop.adafruit.com/datasheets/Sensirion_Humidity_SHT1x_Datasheet_V5.pdf).  From section 4.3 Temperature

Table 8
d<sub>1</sub>(VDD = 5 Volts) = -40.1°C
d<sub>2</sub> = 0.01°C

T = d<sub>1</sub> + d<sub>2</sub> * SO<sub>T</sub>

```
#define d1 (-40.1 /* degrees C */)
#define d2 (0.01 /* degrees C/d2a */)

#define T_SCALE 10000
#define T_OFFSET ((int)(d1 * SCALE))
#define T_SLOPE  ((int)(d2 * SCALE))

// Sensor output - temperature
// 0 to 0x3FFF (14-bit)
int SOT = readTemperatureRaw();

// temeprature in 1/10,000 degree C
int temperature = (SOT * T_SLOPE) + T_OFFSET;

// With 32-bit `int`, no range issue
// -401000 <= temperature <= 1237300
```

Comment: How did you guess which HW the OP is using ?

Comment: OK, I missed that. We can delete these comments. I'll delete mine

Comment: Hi all, thanks you for your help. The sensor is actually the sht10 from adafruit. There is a library availale for the sensor which is where I got the values from [https://github.com/practicalarduino/SHT1x/blob/master/SHT1x.cpp].